# Different color to noise marker using here maps

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

Is it possible to apply different color to different noise markers while clustering using here maps api?

There's a [theming option](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/clustering.html) available, but that applies to all markers. I would like to set a specific color to specific point based on certain conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible using a custom theme. The definition of the `H.clustering.DataPoint` object includes a `data()` [method](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-clustering-datapoint.html#h-clustering-datapoint__data) which can hold arbitrary data.

When you prepare your dataset you can add it as shown:

```
var dataPoints = [];

dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(lat, lng, null, {color :'red'}));
dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(lat, lng, null, {color :'green'}));
dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(lat, lng, null, {color :'blue'}));
// etc ...
```

If you use a custom theme, you can read the data from the noise point and display it as you see fit:

```
function colorfulClusteringTheme() {
    var baseTheme = new H.clustering.DefaultTheme();
    this.getClusterPresentation = function (cluster) {

      var clusterIcon = baseTheme.getClusterPresentation(cluster).getIcon();
          return new H.map.Marker(cluster.getPosition(), {
              icon: clusterIcon,
          min: cluster.getMinZoom(),
          max: cluster.getMaxZoom()
        });

    };
    this.getNoisePresentation = function (noisePoint) {
       if (noisePoint.data.color === 'red'){
          // add red noise point
          return new H.map.Marker(noisePoint.getPosition(), { icon: redIcon });
       }
       if (noisePoint.data.color === 'green'){
          // add red marker
          return new H.map.Marker(noisePoint.getPosition(), { icon: greenIcon });
       }
        if (noisePoint.data.color === 'blue'){
          // add blue noise point
          return new H.map.Marker(noisePoint.getPosition(), { icon: blueIcon });
       }
    };
  };
```

You can add the theme to the map in the usual manner:

```
var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
    clusteringOptions: {
      eps: 16,
      minWeight: 5
    },
    theme: new colorfulClusteringTheme()
  });

  var clusteringLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);
  map.addLayer(clusteringLayer);
```

Comment: Just one thing: it seems that the clustering is working (showing the amount of points), but also I'm seeing all the noise markers like if they are not beign clustered.

Comment: You are probably adding your `markers` directly to the `map` - there is no need to do this, the clustering does it for you, just create `dataPoints`. Alternatively set the `minZoom` as shown in this  [spiderify example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185693/how-to-distinct-two-markers-placed-at-the-same-coordinates-in-nokia-here-map/28064566#28064566)

Comment: Yes! the minZoom was the missing option. Again, thank you very much!!

Comment: If anyone come across "color is undefined" issue you can use the below code.
noisePoint.data.color => noisePoint.getData().color